# getting a warning in Dictionary Learning by using scikit-learn lib

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting a warning sometimes not all times when I am trying to learn a `Dictionary` using `scikit-learn` lib.

Here is my code =>

```
n_iter = 1000
dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_components=100,alpha=3,n_iter=n_iter)

V = dico.fit(data).components_
```

warning is =>

> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py:309:
>   ConvergenceWarning: Regressors in active set degenerate. Dropping a
>   regressor, after 12 iterations, i.e. alpha=3.298e-02, with an active
>   set of 8 regressors, and the smallest cholesky pivot element being
>   2.220e-16   ConvergenceWarning)

I don't know why I am getting this warning?

Comment: Those a numerical-issues observed internally. Maybe your dataset is too large. You should also try to normalize your dataset! And of course there are other hyperparams to tune: batch-size, alpha...

Comment: if u don't mind can i personally contact with u by FB,or mail? I think u have worked on Image processing.

Comment: No sorry. Your best chance is to improve your questions. This most of the time includes adding runnable code with available images (e.g. by using the test-images within scipy / scikit-image). (I'm also not much into image-processing. I'm more into optimization in general)